# Unable to update symfony/finder 5.1.0 to 5.1.1 via composer - it just empties the whole directory

Tags: symfony, composer-php

The package symfony/finder is a transitive dependency in my app. I've tried to do `composer update` and got this output:

```
user@host:/var/www$ composer update && composer check
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)         
Package operations: 0 installs, 51 updates, 0 removals
  - Updating symfony/finder (v5.1.0 => v5.1.2): 
In ClassLoader.php line 444:

  [ErrorException]                                                                                                                       
  include(/var/www/vendor/composer/../symfony/finder/Comparator/NumberComparator.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  


Exception trace:
  at /var/www/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php:444
 Composer\Util\ErrorHandler::handle() at /var/www/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php:444
 include() at /var/www/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php:444
 Composer\Autoload\includeFile() at /var/www/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php:322
 Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader->loadClass() at n/a:n/a
 spl_autoload_call() at /var/www/vendor/symfony/finder/Finder.php:125
 Symfony\Component\Finder\Finder->depth() at /var/www/vendor/composer/composer/src/Composer/Util/Filesystem.php:77
 Composer\Util\Filesystem->emptyDirectory() at /var/www/vendor/composer/composer/src/Composer/Downloader/FileDownloader.php:123
 Composer\Downloader\FileDownloader->doDownload() at /var/www/vendor/composer/composer/src/Composer/Downloader/FileDownloader.php:97
 Composer\Downloader\FileDownloader->download() at /var/www/vendor/composer/composer/src/Composer/Downloader/ArchiveDownloader.php:38
 Composer\Downloader\ArchiveDownloader->download() at /var/www/vendor/composer/composer/src/Composer/Downloader/ZipDownloader.php:77
 Composer\Downloader\ZipDownloader->download() at /var/www/vendor/composer/composer/src/Composer/Downloader/FileDownloader.php:225
 Composer\Downloader\FileDownloader->update() at /var/www/vendor/composer/composer/src/Composer/Downloader/DownloadManager.php:271
 Composer\Downloader\DownloadManager->update() at /var/www/vendor/composer/composer/src/Composer/Installer/LibraryInstaller.php:218
 Composer\Installer\LibraryInstaller->updateCode() at /var/www/vendor/composer/composer/src/Composer/Installer/LibraryInstaller.php:120
 Composer\Installer\LibraryInstaller->update() at /var/www/vendor/composer/composer/src/Composer/Installer/InstallationManager.php:193
 Composer\Installer\InstallationManager->update() at /var/www/vendor/composer/composer/src/Composer/Installer/InstallationManager.php:160
 Composer\Installer\InstallationManager->execute() at /var/www/vendor/composer/composer/src/Composer/Installer.php:611
 Composer\Installer->doInstall() at /var/www/vendor/composer/composer/src/Composer/Installer.php:232
 Composer\Installer->run() at /var/www/vendor/composer/composer/src/Composer/Command/UpdateCommand.php:163
 Composer\Command\UpdateCommand->execute() at /var/www/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php:258
 Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() at /var/www/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:911
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() at /var/www/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:264
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() at /var/www/vendor/composer/composer/src/Composer/Console/Application.php:281
 Composer\Console\Application->doRun() at /var/www/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:140
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at /var/www/vendor/composer/composer/src/Composer/Console/Application.php:113
 Composer\Console\Application->run() at /var/www/vendor/composer/composer/bin/composer:62
```

I've checked and it turned out that directory `/var/www/vendor//symfony/finder` is just completely empty. I've tried updating to 5.1.1 and the result was the same. Running `composer dump` didn't help either.

So I had to add symfony/finder 5.1.0 as a dependency in my app to keep Composer working. And it helped - every other package updated without a hitch.

I'm not familiar with the Symfony ecosystem and don't know where to look for solutions: search results came up empty and the issues functionality is disabled at https://github.com/symfony/finder.

I'm running Composer 1.10.7 inside a Docker container.
Here is what composer.json looks like:

```
{
    "name": "name",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "",
    "license": "proprietary",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.4.3",
        "ext-decimal": "^1.1",
        "ext-dom": "*",
        "ext-ftp": "*",
        "ext-intl": "*",
        "ext-json": "*",
        "ext-libxml": "*",
        "ext-pdo": "*",
        "ext-redis": "*",
        "ext-simplexml": "*",
        "ext-sync": "*",
        "ext-xhprof": "^2.2",
        "ext-xml": "*",
        "ext-zip": "*",
        "alhimik1986/php-excel-templator": "^1.0",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.2",
        "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^1.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.3",
        "laravel/framework": "^7.0",
        "laravel/horizon": "^4.3",
        "laravel/telescope": "^3.2",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.0",
        "pbweb/xhprof": "^1.0",
        "php-decimal/laravel": "^1.1",
        "php-decimal/php-decimal": "^1.1",
        "phpoffice/phpexcel": "^1.8",
        "phpoffice/phpspreadsheet": "1.12.*",
        "propaganistas/laravel-phone": "^4.2",
        "webmozart/assert": "^1.8"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "barryvdh/laravel-debugbar": "^3.3",
        "barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper": "^2.7",
        "doctrine/dbal": "~2.10",
        "facade/ignition": "^2.0",
        "friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer": "^2.16",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.9.1",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.3.1",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^4.1",
        "nunomaduro/larastan": "^0.6",
        "phpstan/phpstan": "^0.12",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.1",
        "rector/rector": "^0.7",
        "roave/security-advisories": "dev-master",
        "sebastian/phpcpd": "^5.0",
        "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "^3.5",
        "timacdonald/log-fake": "^1.6"
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true,
        "process-timeout": 0
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": []
        }
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        },
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories"
        ],
        "files": [
            "app/Helpers/system.php"
        ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ],
        "cs": [
            "./vendor/bin/phpcs --standard=./config/tools/phpcs.xml ./app/ ./tests/"
        ],
        "cs-fix": [
            "php vendor/bin/php-cs-fixer fix"
        ],
        "cpd": [
            "./vendor/bin/phpcpd ./app/ ./resources/views/"
        ],
        "phpstan": [
            "./vendor/bin/phpstan analyse -c /var/www/config/tools/phpstan.neon"
        ],
        "churn": [
            "./vendor/bin/churn run -c ./config/tools/churn.yml ./app/ ./tests/"
        ],
        "check": [
            "./check-code-health.sh"
        ],
        "test:features": [
            "composer test -- --testsuite Feature"
        ],
        "test:features:verbose": [
            "composer test:verbose -- --testsuite Feature"
        ],
        "test:unit": [
            "composer test -- --testsuite Unit"
        ],
        "test:unit:verbose": [
            "composer test:verbose -- --testsuite Unit"
        ],
        "test:unit:coverage": [
            "composer test:coverage -- --testsuite Unit"
        ],
        "test:verbose": [
            "./vendor/bin/phpunit --configuration=./config/tools/phpunit.xml --do-not-cache-result --colors=always --testdox --verbose"
        ],
        "test:coverage": [
            "composer test -- --coverage-html=./storage/coverage"
        ],
        "test": [
            "./vendor/bin/phpunit --configuration=./config/tools/phpunit.xml --do-not-cache-result --colors=always"
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens if you delete composer.lock and in your composer.json you make the dependency 5.1.1 (or even 5.1.* since the latest stable is 5.1.2) and then run composer install?

Comment: "the issues functionality is disabled", it clearly says in the description (on the page you linked) that issues should be posted in the main repository: https://github.com/symfony/symfony where issues are enabled. However, since the operation failed in the update phase (I would say), I would rather try removing the vendor dir first

Comment: @MartinM. exactly the same error.

Comment: @Jakumi, thanks, missed it. Although I'm not sure it is a problem with the package, since composer itself depends on it.
Yes, nuking the whole dir might be a solution, but I would like to find and eliminate the root cause.

Comment: the root cause may very well be a dirty vendor dir ;o) happens from time to time, especially if some composer operation failed before due to unrelated errors. I mean, your diagnosis seems to be correct, if the directory of finder is empty, something failed.

Comment: It looks pretty strange that any classloader is triggered while the upgrade is still running - can you share more details? I've updated an app to Symfony 5.1 in the last week without any problems

Comment: @NicoHaase I can't think of any more details that I can add. Maybe you can suggest something?

Comment: like ... what happened after you deleted the vendor dir and run `composer update` again. or if that doesn't already fix it, what your composer.json looks like (so we can verify the problem), or what composer version you're running.

Comment: @Jakumi, ok, so deleting the vendor dir helped, which was expected. I've added composer version and composer.json content to the question.

Comment: Also I've added exception trace - trying to debug the error. Clearly it has something to do with `Composer\Util\Filesystem->emptyDirectory()`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem turned out to be with invalid `$PATH`. I've had `export PATH="/var/www/vendor/bin:$PATH"` in `~/.bashrc`, so `composer update` was using composer inside a vendor directory which was being updated.

Running `php composer.phar update` solved the problem since phar has it's dependencies (namely symfony/finder) bundled inside.

Comment: was about to write an answer, but yeah, that's my diagnosis too ^^ I'm wondering though: do you have composer/composer as a dependency (maybe indirect) in your project? because you shouldn't have... and maybe you should have a look at how it ended up there. (if you're using docker, maybe some step put it there ...)

Comment: @Jakumi, yeah it's a transitive dependency: ```user@host:/var/www$ composer why composer/composer
barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper  v2.7.0  requires  composer/composer (^1.6)          
nunomaduro/larastan          v0.6.0  requires  composer/composer (^1.0 || ^2.0)```. I guess I'll just leave it is is. Thanks for your help - you definitely steered me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the `php composer.phar update` solution already mentioned, another option is to put `vendor/bin` at the end of `$PATH` rather than at the front.

If `vendor/bin` is at the front of `$PATH`, composer might run from a local installation if you have a package like `nunomaduro/larastan` that depends on it.   Upgrades to seemingly-unrelated packages like `symfony/finder` will then fail with references to missing files because they've been deleted as part of the normal upgrade process which also happened to break that local composer installation that you may not have realized you were using in the first place.

If `vendor/bin` is at the end of `$PATH`, all that is avoided and you still have access to project-specific executables in `vendor/bin`. That should work as long as you're not relying on `vendor/bin` to overshadow things in other places.